# Form Validation not working using onclick and window.open

Tags: validation, onclick, window.open

I have tried so much to get this form work. Earlier only the "window.open" statement wasn't working but now "alert" has also stopped working like the function is not working at all.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Validation
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function myfunction()
        {
        var a=GetElementById("log");
        var b=GetElementById("pwd");
        if (a=="log" && b=="pwd")
        {
            window.open("https://www.google.com");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Your username or password is wrong");
        }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        Name: <input type="textbox" id="log" name="log"> <br>
        Password: <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onsubmit="myfunction();">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now your form itself gets submit, also there is no `GetElementById()` in js, use `document.getElementById()`. Try out the below changes.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var a = document.getElementById("log").value; /* changed */
  var b = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
  if (a == "abc" && b == "123") {
    window.open("https://www.google.com");
  } else {
    alert("Your username or password is wrong");
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" onsubmit="return myfunction();">
  <!-- moved -->
  Name: <input type="textbox" id="log" name="log"> <br> Password: <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd"> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, Arvind for helping but it still didn't work.

Comment: @AbhishekKataria, did you check for errors? Press F12 to launch Developer panel then go to console tab and check for errors, if any.